# Testing a create-react-app using Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, jestjs, create-react-app

I'm building a React app using create-react-app and Firebase (Cloud Firestore).  I'll be using some context providers which pull data from Firebase.

I'm looking for recommendations on resources to look at how to test these components without pinging Firebase each time.

I've looked at the [firebase-mock](https://github.com/soumak77/firebase-mock/blob/HEAD/tutorials/client/firestore.md) repository, but I'm unsure if this is the right strategy going forward.

Does anyone have experience or a code sample with something

Comment: why would u want to do that?

Comment: There is an [emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator) for Cloud Firestore (including security rules), and Cloud Functions, but unfortunately it doesn't support web clients yet.